# Two dynamic DOM elements and positioning after animations?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, architecture

So I have table and menus, which I want to place near selected element.

For example, table slides down from one line and there is transition, so I can't instantly take relative offset and set it to menu. I should do it after transition is complete.

So, talking in abstract way, I should emit event about selection of element when table is fully displayed. Or I should display all table and then select element, so menu will know where to go.

The problem is: I dunno how to subscribe on transition end.

Yea, I can recalculate position of menu in `$watch`, but I don't feel like I need a new watcher here.

How it could be implemented on ReactJS, for example? I use angularjs, but the point is - I don't need to use two-way-binding here.

Any thoughts?

**Btw**: I can't rely on angular-animate since it requires classes to be used, but I have to play with css dynamic attributes instead. And no, it is not possible to rewrite it to use classes, yes I tried. It will not work by the possibilities of css.

Comment: Are you going to use angular-animate?

Comment: Well, this option is not available, sadly :( Updated first post

Comment: you can use it and run jquery.animate from within the add and remove class event

Comment: I use a mix of `.css()` and class changes on this example - http://plnkr.co/edit/RnlKs0dTzhlbAb0g49MC?p=preview.